# Tableview shaking while scrolling in ios 8 & 9 swift

Tags: swift, ios8, heightforrowatindexpath

I have used autolayout on tableview but set frame of image , title & subtitle & height is calculating in HeightforRowAtIndexPath . & scroll tableview shaking

Comment: Please provide some code. In order to someone can help you.

Answer (score 2):

try this in viewDidLoad()

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = largetCellHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps for applying auto layout constraints:

1) Set Leading, Trailing, Top and Bottom Constraints equal to zero for UITableView

2) In UITableViewCell, inside the content view, Set constraints for UIImageView as Leading, Top, Botttom equal to 5 and Aspct ratio to 1:1

3) Set the height of title label half the height of UIImageView. Apply leading, top and trailing constraints equals to 5 for this title label.

4) Place a subtitle label just below title label, and set it's heigh tequal to half of UIImageView height. Set leading, trailing abd bottom constraints to this subtitle label equals to 5.

5) Apply aspect ratio constraint to any one of those two labels.

5) You can also select two labels and apply equal height and equal width constraint

6) Finally, apply top constraint for subtitle label w.r.t titleLabel, equal to zero.

7) Now you can implement UITableView's heightForRowAtIndexPath method and return the desired height value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nilesh . Actually I have tried all solutions , like estimated row height method , so rework to frame calculation and gives accurate height in heightForRow method still table view is shaking on ipad . or if every things are file but when pop to view again start shaking probles

Comment: One more think I have a custom section header view for nib & I have created custom section header using autolayout

Comment: Cashed image are of any size but I have to resize image so that image should not starched & Should align top & left in cell